# Flatten out data from database table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have data in the table form as :

```
Grade |  TimeInterval |  SubjectName
1        0               History
1        1               Chemistry
1        3               Biology
2        0               Maths
2        2               Biology
2        3               History
3        0               Biology
3        1               History
3        2               Chemistry
3        3               Maths
```

I want to convert the above data into following format, what is the best way to do it.

```
Grade TimeInterval0 TimeInterval1 TimeInterval2 TimeInterval3
1     History       Chemistry     Empty         Biology
2     Maths         Empty          Biology      History
3     Biology       History        Chemistry    Maths
```

I do not know if I can use the PIVOT transformation directly since the TimeInterval in my original source data is coming as 0,1,2 Whereas in the my flattened destination table column name is specified as TimeInterval0, TimeInterval1, TimeInterval2, etc.

I cannot change the schema since it already has much data and many other tables are interlinked with each other.

Comment: Are there only 4 time intervals? (0,1,2,3)

Comment: There are 0-15, but they can increase in future. For sample i took 0-3.

Comment: You can still use PIVOT and then create aliases for the columns in an outer query

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a manual pivot. This allows you to control the column names etc, but you have to do all the pivot work yourself. Something like this

```
Select G.Grade
    , Int0.SubjectName as TimeInterval0
    , Int1.SubjectName as TimeInterval1
    , Int2.SubjectName as TimeInterval2
    , Int3.SubjectName as TimeInterval3
from (Select distinct Grade from SourceTable) G
    left outer join SourceTable Int0 on Int0.Grade = G.Grade and Int0.TimeInterval = 0
    left outer join SourceTable Int1 on Int1.Grade = G.Grade and Int1.TimeInterval = 1
    left outer join SourceTable Int2 on Int2.Grade = G.Grade and Int2.TimeInterval = 2
    left outer join SourceTable Int3 on Int3.Grade = G.Grade and Int3.TimeInterval = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always *rename* columns using column aliases in an outer query. Here I'm using a CTE.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp;
CREATE TABLE #temp (Grade INT,  TimeInterval INT, SubjectName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT #temp
(
    Grade,
    TimeInterval,
    SubjectName
)
VALUES
    (1,        0,               'History    '),
    (1,        1,               'Chemistry  '),
    (1,        3,               'Biology    '),
    (2,        0,               'Maths      '),
    (2,        2,               'Biology    '),
    (2,        3,               'History    '),
    (3,        0,               'Biology    '),
    (3,        1,               'History    '),
    (3,        2,               'Chemistry  '),
    (3,        3,               'Maths      ');


WITH pivoted AS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM #temp
   PIVOT ( 
       MAX(SubjectName) FOR TimeInterval IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
   ) pvt
)
SELECT grade,
       [TimeInterval0] = pivoted.[0],
       [TimeInterval1] = pivoted.[1],
       [TimeInterval2] = pivoted.[2],
       [TimeInterval3] = pivoted.[3]
FROM pivoted
```

Answer (score 0):

> Intervals are 0-15, but they can increase in future

You need a `dynamic pivot`

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData (Grade INT,  TimeInterval INT, SubjectName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT SampleData
(
    Grade,
    TimeInterval,
    SubjectName
)
VALUES
    (1,        0,               'History    '),
    (1,        1,               'Chemistry  '),
    (1,        3,               'Biology    '),
    (2,        0,               'Maths      '),
    (2,        2,               'Biology    '),
    (2,        3,               'History    '),
    (3,        0,               'Biology    '),
    (3,        1,               'History    '),
    (3,        2,               'Chemistry  '),
    (3,        3,               'Maths      ');

DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cols = STUFF(
                    (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(',[', t.TimeInterval, ']') FROM SampleData t FOR XML PATH (''))
                   ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @headers nvarchar(max)

SELECT @headers = STUFF(
                    (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(', [' , t.TimeInterval , '] AS [TimeInterval' , t.TimeInterval, ']') FROM SampleData t FOR XML PATH (''))
                   ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'Select [Grade],  ' + @headers + 
        ' FROM 
         (
            SELECT Grade, TimeInterval, SubjectName FROM  SampleData
         ) src
         PIVOT
         (
            MAX(SubjectName) FOR TimeInterval IN ('+ @cols+ ')
         ) pvt
        '
PRINT @query

EXEC (@query)

DROP TABLE SampleData
```

Demo here http://rextester.com/LIW80994